# Corona apk expansion not working

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk, apk-expansion-files

I tried using the expansion file setting and config on the new update but it only made one apk that is 100mb. Is there something else to it besides the build and config settings?

```
-- Android permissions

    usesExpansionFile = true,

    -- The following permissions are required to download expansion files.
    usesPermissions =
    {
        "android.permission.INTERNET",
        "com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE",
        "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
        "android.permission.INTERNET"
    },
```

and this is my config

```
license =
{
    google =
    {
        key = "**********",
        policy = "this is optional",
    },
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the fix, but you're missing a `,` after `"android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"`, so it should be `"android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",`.